# Find the minimum value of $f(x)= N-x^{\lfloor log_x(N)\rfloor}$ for $1 <x < 1000$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions

Is there any efficient way to find the $x$ value for which $f(x)$ is the minimum in the range of $1 < x < 1000$ so that

$$f(x)= N-x^{\large{\lfloor \log_x(N)\rfloor}}\;?$$

Note: $N,x$ are positive integers and $N\gt x$.

Comment: What was wrong with the previous post?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I got it completely messed up, this post is my actual question.

Comment: Okay but I was giving a suggestion when the question was abruptly deleted.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I am sorry if it's still relevant you can give it now.

Comment: Did you use any particular value for $N$? Try using a large one (not Graham's number). How about $10^{100}$? Then plot a graph or use a graphing software to plot a graph of $y = f(x)$. Use the graph to find the minimum value of $f(x)$. Then try again with larger numbers to find a pattern or a constant.

Comment: Thank you, this suggestion is good for solving problems in general...

Comment: I think GeoGebra *might* help but as you very well know normal calculators can not even compute $10^{100}$, let alone anything larger. So it might not work. Hope that it works so that a solution is found.

Comment: You probably should have made explicit that $x$ shall assume integer values only. Looks like the answerer took it to take arbitrary real values between $1$ and $1000$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Perfect thank you, I update the question.

Comment: The artificial fixed upper bound for $x$ feels like the question is based on a problem from some programming contest. If this is not the case, what is the reason for this upper bound? Otherwise, if it indeed comes from a contest, is the actual problem _really_ asking just for $x<1000$ (in which case it strongly looks like a candidate for a simple exhaustive search -- improving on an already-small constant is rarely needed) or is it something more general (like, "find the closest perfect power not exceeding $N$")?

Comment: @PeterKošinár yeah there is an actual constant value there, it's not 1000 but $256^4$ or Integer.MAX_VALUE, I just thought that using the value 1000 will make it easier to explain the problem. Also, $N$ max value is $256^{1024}$ that is the block size in my app.

Comment: The different values of $N$ and $x_{\text{max}}$ change the approach for practical computing.  For $x_{\text{max}}=1000$ it is quite  reasonable to check all the possible $x$'s.  For $x_{\text{max}}=256^4=2^{32}$ it is still reasonable, though harder (minutes or hours instead of fractional seconds).  Now you can save substantial computer time by finding a range of $x$'s for which the same maximum power applies and ignore all but the largest.

Comment: I would still be tempted to minimize programmer time by taking the simple approach of trying all the $x$'s in range.  Write the program, verify it for small $x,N$ and let it run.  Figuring out which $x$'s you can skip takes (careful) thought.  That's what computers are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's generalize the problem setting a bit: If $x$, $x_{max}$, $y$ and $N$ are positive integers satisfying $$2\leq x\leq x_{max}\leq N$$ and $$x^y\leq N$$ what is the maximum possible value of $x^y$? (answering this is equivalent to minimizing $(N-x^y)$, which is what the original problem is about)

Instead of working with $x^y$, we can also work with $\log x^y = y\log x$, since $\log$ is an increasing function.

There are two similarly straightforward approaches to this problem:

- We can enumerate the possible values of $x$ and see what is the greatest $y$ for which $x^y$ still doesn't exceed $N$. For each given $x$, such an $y$ can be computed directly as $$y=\left\lfloor \log_x N\right\rfloor$$
  Thanks to the identity $$\log_a b = \frac{\log_c a}{\log_c b}$$ we can also rewrite it as $$y=\left\lfloor \frac{\log N}{\log x}\right\rfloor$$ and get $$\log x^y = \left\lfloor \frac{\log N}{\log x}\right\rfloor\log x$$
  In other words, we can compute $\log N$ once and then compute one logarithm for each value of $x$, followed by a few simple arithmetic operations: division, truncation and multiplication. As we only need to test $(x_{max}-1)$ possible values of $x$, we are looking at $\Theta(x_{max})$ operations in total.
- Instead of iterating through possible values of $x$, we can look at possible values of $y$. For a given value of $y$, the best possible $x$ would be $$x=\left\lfloor N^{1/y}\right\rfloor$$
  The given bounds on $x$ can be used to derive bounds on $y$: Since $x\geq 2$, we must have $$y\leq \lfloor \log_2 N\rfloor$$ and the upper bound $x\leq x_{max}$ tells us that we also need to have $$y\geq \left\lfloor\log_{x_{max}} N\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{\log_2 N}{\log_2 x_{max}}\right\rfloor$$
  Since $$N^{1/y}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{y}\log N\right)$$ we can compute $\log N$ once and use it to compute $\log x^y$ for each particular $y$ using one exponentiation and one logarithm (plus the relatively cheap operations of division, multiplication and truncation). Thus, we are looking at $\Theta(\log_2 N)$ operation.

While the analysis above ignored many available optimizations (for example, work purely with integers rather than their logarithms might be more efficient and less error-prone due to underestimated precision), it should be sufficient to suggest that with a fixed $x_{max}$, the second approach is apparently faster when $N$ is smaller, but as $N$ keeps growing, the first one will eventually win -- although the crossover may be too far for any practical purposes.

For example, with $x_{max}=256^4$ and $N\leq 256^{1024}$ (as indicated in the comments of the question), the second approach looks considerably better (since it only needs to test less than $8000$ candidates for $y$, while the naive iteration over $x$ would yield more than $4\cdot 10^9$ tests).

Answer (score 0):

The term $x^{\lfloor log_x(N)\rfloor}$ is the greatest perfect power of a number less than $1000$ that is less than $N$.  This bounces around a lot.  I just did a little sample with $N=123456789$ and restricting $1 \lt x \lt 32$.  The $x$ that gave the minimum was $22$ with $22^6=113379904$ and it looks like $22$ will give the minimum up to $3^{17}=129140163$, then it stays $3$ until $2^{27}=134217728$  With $N$ this small you have a whole range of exponents that round down to the same power of $x$, so you can ignore all of them until the last where the exponent takes a drop.  For my example of $N=123456789$ the exponent on $x$ is $6$ for $15$ through $22$ so we can ignore $15-21$.  When $N$ gets very large you won't have that any more, so I don't think there is an efficient way.

Comment: Can you prove that there is no efficient way solving this?

Comment: No, I can't.  The threshold for where the exponent is never the same is around $1000^{6902}=10^{20706}$  After that I think you are reduced to searching the powers.  You can skip all the perfect powers below $1000$ because the value for $x=8$ can never be better than the value for $x=2$, but that only saves $40$ or so.

Comment: I would like to see a comment from the downvoter to explain why this is not helpful.  I recognize that it is not a full answer but think it too large for a comment.